# C# Using ILnumerics to plot in 3d

Tags: c#, ilnumerics

I have been trying for hours now to get **ILNumerics** to work in visual studio(c#) and my question is:

How do I install the plugin so I can use it's features?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beginner ILNumerics: install under VS2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673326/beginner-ilnumerics-install-under-vs2012)

Answer (score 0):

With Visual Studio 2017 the way extensions are handled has changed. It is no longer possible to have a single extension supporting all versions of Visual Studio, including 2010,2012,2013,2015 and 2017. Therefore, we decided to drop VS2010 support with the next major version. Until this is released, the extension must be installed into VS2017 by an additional *manual* installation step.

After installing the ILNumerics download package go into the installation folder. Commonly this is found under: `C:\Program Files (x86)\ILNumerics\ILNumerics Ultimate VS\bin`. In the `bin` folder double click the `ILNumerics.VSExtension.vsix` file. This starts the VS extension installer. Just follow the instructions to install ILNumerics into VS2017. There will be a security related warning along the way which you can ignore.

More info is found in this [blog post](https://ilnumerics.net/blog/release-notes-ilnumerics-4-13-detailed/). Scroll down to the section "Visual Studio 2017 Compatibility".